# How to get fragment tag or ID?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have 2 fragments which are instantiated from the same class as the layouts are identical like so:

```
 getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().
     add(R.id.leftContainer,new LeftFragmentClass(),"leftFrag").commit();
 getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().
    add(R.id.rightFrag,new LeftFragmentClass(),"rightFrag").commit();
```

Within LeftFragmentClass there is a callback method which is called when the button within the fragment is pressed. After this some processing is done and data is displayed, however, right now the callback cannot distinguish which button was pressed. Is there a function which can return which fragment button was pressed?

Comment: Can you show your callback method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this type of condition i create a function inside fragment which will return me the instance of fragment and make the fragment constructor private something like:-

```
public class LeftFragmentClass extends Fragment{
   private String fragmentTag = null;

   public LeftFragmentClass(){}

   public static LeftFragmentClass newInstance(String tag){
       LeftFragmentClass mLeftFragmentClass = new LeftFragmentClass();
       Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
       bundle.putString ("tag",tag);
       mLeftFragmentClass.setArgument(bundle);

       return mLeftFragmentClass;
   }

   @Override
   public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        tag = getArguments().getString("tag")
   }

}
```

So i used newInstance function to create instance of LeftFragmentClass and pass the tag to it which i m setting to Fragment argument using bundle and inside onCreate get bundle using getArguments and from it the tag value. Pass this tag value as one of the parameter to your callback method to identify which button was clicked.

So from activity for getting instance of LeftFragmentClass you can write as

```
LeftFragmentClass mLeftFragmentClassLeft = LeftFragmentClass.newInstance("left")

LeftFragmentClass mLeftFragmentClassRight = LeftFragmentClass.newInstance("Right")
```

==== Edit ====

keep the fragment class constructors always public don't make it private as i suggested above in my sample code. Making it private will cause application to crash with exception

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{MainActivity}:
>   android.support.v4.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to
>   instantiate fragment com.thatswhy.AppAlertDialog: make sure class name
>   exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public

Comment: The newInstance method doesn't return LeftFragmentClass though. Is that allowed?

Comment: Updated. missed to write the return line. actually if you have implemented then you would have got error :).

Comment: So when I instantiate my fragment do I type this:  getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.leftContainer, new LeftFragmentClass().newInstance("leftFrag"),"leftFrag").commit();

Comment: Pl check now, forgot to add newInstance should be static, and you cannot use new LeftFragmentClass() as constructor is already private. Also added code for how to get fragment instance using newInstance.

Comment: Android studio is complaining about the "private LeftFragmentClass(){}" line. It says that the default constructor must be public

Comment: keep it public and use newInstance method won't make a difference. I kept and suggested private constructor to force other users to use newInstance method of the fragment class.

Answer (score 1):

```
Fragment fragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("Tag")
```

Comment: Wouldn't that line of code find the fragment with the tag "Tag"?

Comment: Not really what I'm after

Comment: yes this will find the fragment. in your case tag is: leftFrag

Answer (score 0):

As per provided the info you can do something like this, in your `callback method` pass the `button` object and check accordingly,

Some code snippet to explain the same :

Suppose your callback method is `onButtonClick()` then you can pass `button` object like :

```
public void onButtonClick(Button button){
      // check here with button id
      if(button.getId() == R.id.button1) {

      } else if(button.getId() == R.id.button1) {

      }
}
```

Hope this makes things clear..

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way of doing this I've seen is to create two distinct View.OnClickListener(s) in the Activity.

Have a getter() for each. `public View.OnClickListener getLeftButtonPressed()`, `public View.OnClickListener getRightButtonPressed()`

Then when you instantiate your left and right instances of your fragment, just pass in the appropriate 'View.OnClickListener' to the constructor of the Fragment. This not only reduces the code in the Fragment(s), it also centralizes the 'logic' of what to do when buttons are pressed.

---

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    // create the two listeners
    View.OnClickListener leftButtonListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {
             leftButtonClicked(v);
         }
     });
     View.OnClickListener rightButtonListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {
             rightButtonClicked(v);
         }
     });

     // 2 getters
     public View.OnClickListener getLeftListener() { return this.leftButtonListener; }
     public View.OnClickListener getRightListener() { return this.rightButtonListener; }

 protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
     super.onCreate(icicle);

     setContentView(R.layout.content_layout_id);

 }

 // actual logic of what to do when each button is pressed.
 private void leftButtonClicked(View v){
       // some logic here
 }
 private void rightButtonClicked(View v){
       // some logic here
 }
```

}

This removes you later having to keep track of which button was pressed by making use of strings and if/then/else blocks, etc.

Comment: Sorry if this is a stupid question but how would you pass the onClickListener functions when you instantiate the fragments?

Comment: Change your Fragment's to have a setter method where you set it to the 'clickListener' of that fragment, and then call that method after you get a new instance, but before you finish your 'onCreate()'. You might have to play around with setting it as a 'value' first in the Fragment and THEN setting the button to use it (after the fragment is attached) (fragments have a different life cycle than Activities)

Answer (score 0):

Add a parameter to interface callback function in your fragment;

```
interface Interfacecallback{
public void callbackfunction(int fragid);
}

Interfacecallback interfacecallback;


//in your button click

//pass 1 for fragment right
//pass 2 for fragment left
interfacecallback.callbackfunction(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the fragment tag using this line of code if it exists:-

```
Fragment mapFragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("MapRestaurantFragment");
```